# Refactor circleci config.yml file for ReactJs

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am new to CI/CD. I have created a basic react application using `create-react-app`. I have added the below configuration for circleci. It is working fine in circleci without issues. But there are lot of redundant code like same steps has been used in multiple places. I want to refactor this config file following best practices.

```
 version: 2.1
    orbs:
      node: circleci/node@4.7.0
    
    jobs:
      build:
        docker:
          - image: cimg/node:17.2.0
        steps:
          - checkout
          - node/install-packages:
              pkg-manager: npm
          - run:
              command: npm run build
              name: Build app
          - persist_to_workspace:
              root: ~/project
              paths:
                - .
      test:
        docker:
          - image: cimg/node:17.2.0
        steps:
          - checkout
          - node/install-packages:
              pkg-manager: npm
          - run:
              command: npm run test
              name: Test app
          - persist_to_workspace:
              root: ~/project
              paths:
                - .
      eslint:
        docker:
          - image: cimg/node:17.2.0
        steps:
          - checkout
          - node/install-packages:
              pkg-manager: npm
          - run:
              command: npm run lint
              name: Lint app
          - persist_to_workspace:
              root: ~/project
              paths:
                - .
    workflows:
      on_commit:
        jobs:
          - build
          - test
          - eslint
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see you are installing packages for multiple jobs. You can check about [save_cache](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#savecache) and [restore_cache](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference/#restorecache) options.